# htaccess rewrite and redirect url from character %26 to &

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a following URL and it works perfectly like the following:

```
http://www.naturaflowers.com/garland-&-wreaths/garland.html
```

Now google webmaster crawl the site and fetch the same URL in two format like the following and show duplicate error

```
http://www.naturaflowers.com/garland-&-wreaths/garland.html
http://www.naturaflowers.com/garland-%26-wreaths/garland.html
```

Now I want to redirect %26 to & character so that it will not show the duplicate in google web master. Please help me to overcome this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /garland-%26-wreaths/garland.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)garland-&-wreaths/garland.html$ /$1garland-&-wreaths/garland.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sir can you do me a favor? Right now it's static for every URL. I want to make it dynamic I mean each and every time garland-%26-wreath change to garland-&-wreath, is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible to redirect the URL from garland-%26-wreaths to garland-&-wreaths from middle of any url string?